# ExtJS: beforerender bug

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4.2.1:

```
beforerender: function() {
    console.log('beforerender');
}
```

outputs

```
> beforerender
```

but

```
beforerender: function() {
    console.log('beforerender');
    return false;
}
```

outputs

```
> beforerender
> beforerender
```

Is this intended behavior?

I return `false` to delay the rendering of my component until some things are setup (ex. loading some remote stores), then manually call `doLayout()` on the container in callbacks to render on-demand.

Comment: Maybe `doLayout()` fires `beforerender` again ?

Comment: According to http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-doLayout it does not fire an event. Try to console.log in your callbacks to find out how it works.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer the part about `doLayout()` was just for people wondering why I would return `false`. This code, as is (without manual calls to `doLayout()`), fires `beforerender` twice

Comment: So just returning false makes the event fire a second time ? Indeed, this seems a strange behavior.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer correct; returning false makes the event fire a second time. I don't understand.